# Help needed with commas in a sentence

Tags: commas

I am struggling to properly use commas in the following sentence.

> It was the invention of integrated circuits in 1949 which made the
> smartphones that we use today possible.

I think I should right it as:

> It was the invention of integrated circuits in 1949 which made the
> smartphones, that we use today, possible.

But I am not sure about it. Please help me with this.

Comment: "the discovery of integrated circuits in 1949" Really? 1949? Are you sure about that? Also weren't they invented or developed? We 'discover' things that are already there.

Comment: https://www.thoughtco.com/history-of-integrated-circuit-aka-microchip-1992006

Comment: *It was the invention of integrated circuits in 1949 that made the smartphones that we use today possible.*  No extra punctuation needed.

Comment: I think you meant “I should *write* it”. Your rewrite hasn’t *righted* it. The original was already ‘right’ - grammatically, at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the convention that is commoner in American English, which I suggest you do, defining clauses are linked by the relative pronoun “that”, which is never preceded by a comma, and descriptive clauses are linked by the relative pronouns “which” and “who”;  “which” and “who” are always preceded by a comma and their clauses end with a comma (or full stop.)

All the subordinate clauses in the example are defining clauses, thus “that” is used throughout and there are no commas:

{It was the invention of integrated circuits in 1949} [that] made {the smartphones [that we use today]} possible.

“It” is the preparatory or dummy “it”

The first “that” is a pronoun with the referent “it” and "it" has the referent “the invention of integrated circuits”

The sentence can be restated as either

The invention of integrated circuits was in 1949. That invention of integrated circuits made possible the smartphones that we use today.

Or

The invention of integrated circuits [in 1949] made {the smartphones [that we use today]} possible.

Comment: ICs were first demonstrated as laboratory prototypes around 1957 and mass produced from the later 1960s, and didn't get into smartphones until maybe 2005.

Comment: ICs were first demonstrated as laboratory prototypes around 1957 and mass produced from the later 1960s, and didn't get into cell phones until the 1990s and smartphones didn't even exist until the 21st century.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but right now, I just want to know if the sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: If you asked if this sentence were correct, why do you think you should not get a certain amount of querying responses "It was the invention of horses in the 19th century that made cowboys possible"?